# Como quitar el ultimo carácter del ";" de un stringBuilder en java

Tags: java

Amigos un gusto saludarlos, espero y me puedan ayudar con problema un tanto peculiar, lo que sucede es que concateno cadenas con cada condición que arroje las validaciones `if`, hay un detalle como se aprecia en la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El ultimo punto y coma lo quiero quitar, ya que no tiene caso que se muestra si ya no hay mas cadenas, hay alguna manera de poder borrarlo?

Este es mi codigo:

```
StringBuilder notas = new StringBuilder(""); 
notas.append("Archivo no tiene fecha Exdate o Excupón");
 if(notas.length()>0)
        notas.append(";");
```

Cuando la variable nota tenga una cadena, es decir, que si la longitud de esa cadena es mayor, pues que agregue el punto y coma, eso lo hace bien, pero el problema es como lo comenté arriba, pone punto y coma, espero que con lo que puse me pueda dar a entender, y al igual espero y me puedan ayudar o brindarme alguno tips, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes buscar el ";" con **lastIndexOf**(";"), y si es el ultimo carácter de la cadena que lo quite, como se muestre a continuación:

```
StringBuilder notas = new StringBuilder("");
int ultimaComa = 0;
notas.append("Archivo no tiene fecha Exdate o Excupón");
if (notas.length() > 0){
   notas.append(";");
   ultimaComa = notas.lastIndexOf(";");
}


if(ultimaComa==(notas.length()-1) && notas.length() > 0) {
    notas = new StringBuilder(notas.substring(0, notas.length()-1));
}
System.out.println(notas);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sbCadena=new StringBuilder();
String str1="text1;";
String str2="text2;";
sbCadena.append(str1);
sbCadena.append(str2);
sbCadena.deleteCharAt(sbCadena.length()-1);//elimina caracter en posición especificada,
                                           //en tu caso ultima posición=length()-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eliminar el **;** que se coloca al final, puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera, en la cual obtienes el ultimo carácter de tu cadena final y aplicas un  **deleteCharAt**

```
public class Ejemplo{

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    StringBuilder notas = new StringBuilder("");
    notas.append("Archivo no tiene fecha Exdate o Excupón");
    if (notas.length() > 0)
        notas.append(";");

    System.out.println(notas);
    // Obtienes el ultimo caracter de la cadena y lo eliminas con la siguiente
    // sentencia.
    notas.deleteCharAt(notas.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(notas);
  }

}
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]